# Rails AJAX Passing Variable From Controller to Partial Not Working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm having an issue with passing a variable from my controller to a partial asynchronously. What I'd like to happen is for a form to be rendered on my view after the user selects an option from a drop down menu. The problem is that I keep getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `shipment_options' for #<#    <Class:0x007f92941be8f0>:0x007f929ca78ad8>
```

even if I use something like `locals: { var: @var }` or something like that. Here's the code from my view:

```
<body>
  <p>
    This is the body<br>

    <%= select_tag :service, options_for_select(usps_services), { id: "service_select", remote: true } %><br>

  <div id='shipment_option'>
    <%= render 'shipment_option', remote: true, locals: { shipments: @shipment_options } %>

  </div>
</body>
<script>
$('#service_select').on('change', function () {
    var service = $('#service_select').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/service_select',
      format: 'js',
      data: { service: service, order_id: <%= params[:order_id] %> },
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.rates);
        return true;
      },
      error: function (data) {
        return false;
    }});

});
</script>
```

The route that handles that AJAX request

```
# AJAX
# get '/ajax/:service' => 'dashboards#get_shipment'
post '/service_select' => 'dashboards#get_shipment'
```

The `get_shipment` method in the controller

```
def get_shipment
  order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  respond_to do |format|

  from_address = EasyPost::Address.create(
    :street1 => Rails.configuration.from_address[:street1],
    :street2 => Rails.configuration.from_address[:street2],
    :city => Rails.configuration.from_address[:city],
    :state => Rails.configuration.from_address[:state],
    :zip => Rails.configuration.from_address[:zip]
  )

  to_address = EasyPost::Address.create(
    :name => order.name,
    :street1 => order.street1,
    :street2 => order.street2,
    :city => order.city,
    :state => order.state,
    :zip => order.zip
  )

  parcel = EasyPost::Parcel.create(
    :predefined_package => params[:service],
    :weight => 10
  )

  @shipment_options = EasyPost::Shipment.create(
    :to_address => to_address,
    :from_address => from_address,
    :parcel => parcel
  )
  # format.json { render json: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(shipment_option) }
  format.js { render json: @shipment_options, action: "new" }
end
```

end

And the code in the partial that I'm trying to render

```
<%= form_for(@shipment) do |f| %>
  <% shipment_options.rates.each do |rate| %>
    <%= f.label :shipment_service %> 
    <%= rate.service + " " + rate.rate.to_s %>
    <%= f.check_box :shipment_service %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Ship package" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I get rid of this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem by taking out all of the arguments from `format.js` in my controller, and then making the `.js.erb` to `get_shipment.js.erb`. This then set my `@shipment_options` before I rendered the partial by writing:

```
$('#shipment_option').html("<%= j(render 'shipment_option') %>");
```

The form then rendered properly because I had set the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you passed @shipment_options as shipments to your partial, but in your partial you are calling shipment_options, which hasn't been defined.

Comment: Well even after changing `@shipment_options` to `shipments` as I've passed in the `locals` variable, I'm still getting the same `undefined method` error.

Comment: I think that the error happens because the page is trying to render my partial before there's even been an AJAX call. I just don't know how to make rails "wait" to evaluate/load the partial until after the variable has been set in the controller. I did get this working with just javascript, but I couldn't replicate just using Ruby.

Comment: Oh I see. I assumed you had another controller (which renders the template) that also defines `@shipment_options`'. You actually don't need the ajax request at all if you define `@shipment_options` there. What is in your controller that renders the view?